# convert document to pdf in java using OOo

Tags: java, pdf

I'm looking for a way to convert docx, doc, odt and other documents to PDF using a Java API

I have used JODConverter before, but it's no longer maintained.

Thank you.

Comment: Did JODConvert stop working for you? If it does the job why change?

Comment: Numerous online conversions APIs http://www.convertapi.com/

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it but I know it's there.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.pdf-for-java/default.aspx

Comment: I think that aspose is not free but i am searching for something free and perfect witch use OOo to convert docs